# How to calculate values in the cell to the right if the cell to the left matches a certain criteria

Tags: google-sheets

Sorry if this is confusing. As you can see in the snapshot; in cell S8 I am trying to do a calculation with the numbers in the Order Amounts column in J28:J42 assuming the "allergens" in column I28:I42 match the allergens in column Q8:Q19. I was trying =if(J28:J42==Q8,) to start, then I was lost because I don't know how to reference the cell to the right of J28 if J28 matches Q8 to use that number for a calculation.
[image]

Comment: Kindly change your screenshot above, add sample data (for column I and J) and add another screenshot for the desired output.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the data was not populating.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused on `=if(J28:J42==Q8,)`. Do you want to match Q8:Q23 and I28:I43 then get the corresponding value in column J? Example for Egg It should return 78 to cell S8? Adding screenshot of your desired output in column S would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah. I was hoping to Take the Value in Q8 look for the value in J28:J42. If there is a match, it will display the number in the cell to the right. So Q8 has 'egg', it searches J28:J42 for 'egg'. It shows there is 'egg' in I28, so then it would reference the cell to the right in J28.

Comment: I would then take that number in J28 and include that in a formula in S8 (which I can do alone)

Answer (score 1):

In cell `S8` try this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(Q8:Q23, I28:J43, 2, FALSE))
```

**Sample Data:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)